# Nuxt prerender with nitro - api still called on route change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apollo-client, nuxt3, nitro

I am pre-rendering a selection of pages in my nuxt website. The structure for these pages looks like this,

```
<template>
    <div class="page" v-if="props.uri !== 'our-windows' && props.uri !== 'our-doors'">
      <component
          v-for="(block, index) in pageContent.page[0].builder"
          :key="index"
          :is="resolveComponent(componentMap[block.typeHandle])"
          :block-data="block.data"
          :type-handle="block.typeHandle"
          :show-form="pageContent.page[0].pageDisplayFormInHeroOfPage"
          :initialArticles="pageContent.page[0].children"
          :affiliateId="pageContent.page[0].affiliateId"
          :breadcrumbs="{ 
              current: {
                title: pageContent.page[0].title,
                uri: pageContent.page[0].uri,
                parent: pageContent.page[0].parent
              },
              ancestors: pageContent.page[0].ancestors
            }"
      />
    </div>

    <ProductLandingPage v-else :block-data="pageContent.page[0].builder" :breadcrumbs="{ 
              current: {
                title: pageContent.page[0].title,
                uri: pageContent.page[0].uri,
                parent: pageContent.page[0].parent
              },
              ancestors: pageContent.page[0].ancestors
            }" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

 import { pageQuery } from '~/graphql/queries/Page';
 import { componentMap } from '~/data/component-map'

 const navigationOpen = useState('navigationOpen');
 const route = useRoute();
 const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()

 const props = defineProps({
    uri: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
 })

let { data: pageContent, error } = await useAsyncQuery(pageQuery, { slug: props.uri });

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  navigationOpen.value = false;
})

const parsedTitle = computed(() => {
  const titleObj = JSON.parse(pageContent.value.page[0].seomatic.metaTitleContainer);
  let title = "";
  if(titleObj.title.title == "") {
    title = `${pageContent.value.page[0].title}`
  } else {
    title = titleObj.title.title
  }
  return title;
});

const parsedMeta = computed(() => {
  const metaObj = JSON.parse(pageContent.value.page[0].seomatic.metaTagContainer);
  return metaObj;
});

const parsedSchema = computed(() => {
  const schema = JSON.parse(pageContent.value.page[0].seomatic.metaJsonLdContainer);
  return schema;
});

const parsedMetaLink = computed(() => {
  return JSON.parse(pageContent.value.page[0].seomatic.metaLinkContainer);
});



useSeoMeta({
  charset: 'UTF-8',
  viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no',
  title: parsedTitle.value,
  ogTitle: parsedTitle.value,
  description: parsedMeta.value.description.content,
  ogSiteName: parsedMeta.value['og:site_name'].content,
});

useHead({
  link: [
    {
      rel: 'canonical',
      href: pageContent.value.page[0].uri == 'home' ? `/` : `${parsedMetaLink.value.canonical.href}/`
    },
    {
      rel: 'sitemap',
      href: '/sitemap.xml',
      type: 'application/xml'
    }
  ],
});

useSchemaOrg([
  defineWebSite(parsedSchema),
  defineWebPage(),
])

</script>
```

The pages render fine on build and I can see the generated pages in the browser, however the idea behind pre-rendering these pages was to stop the need for the api call on each route change, however as I move around the I can still see my api being called for data, but as they are rendered already this is a call I do not need and is slowing down the page load. Is there away to only do `let { data: pageContent, error } = await useAsyncQuery(pageQuery, { slug: props.uri });` if the page is not rerendered?